# Google App Engine Datastore .put() and .get() methods not working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to select an entity from one table of the datastore, get some information out of it, and then put that information into an entity in a different table.  The `put()` and `get()` methods don't seem to be working though and I can't figure out why.

```
aName = 'Hello'
q = firstTable.all()
q.filter("date =", datetime.date.today())
dateInfo = q.get() # get method here works fine
p = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM secondTable WHERE name = '%s'" % aName)
result = p.run(limit = 1) # here, there's an error if I use get(), but no error if I use run()

result.firstProperty = dateInfo.firstProperty
result.secondProperty = dateInfo.secondProperty

result.put() # this line does not work
```

- Any idea what could be wrong here?
- Could a problem in the entities themselves cause this behavior?
- Particularly perplexing to me is that the `.run()` method works for `p`, but the `.get()` does not work. 
  What could cause that?

The error message in the log:

```
'_QueryIterator' object has no attribute 'put' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/thir
```

The way I know that certain lines don't work is that, when I comment out those particular lines, the page loads and doesn't throw the above error.

If I try to use `.get()` instead of `.run()`, then it gives this error:

```
raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property info is required
```

Comment: You should actually show what the error is, rather than the vague "there's an error here" and "this line does not work". Error messages convey useful information that is vital in debugging.

Comment: I've added the error message as you suggest.  It's just the generic server error message, so not that helpful unfortunately.  Do you know of a way to access more detailed error messages?  That would help enormously.  Thanks!

Comment: In the log section of the app engine console site.

Comment: That is amazingly helpful, thank you, and apologies for my noobishness.  I've added the detailed error message now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because `run` causes the query to be run, returning an iterator which you need to iterate over the results. It doesn't directly return an entity.

In your case you are trying to update the iterator itself and then call `put()` which of course fails.

Even with a limit of 1, you need to iterate.

You should be using `get`, however, you point out you get an error:

```
error: raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name) BadValueError: Property info is required
```

This is because you have changed a property in your model `info` and added `required=True` but you have some old data in the datastore that has no value for `info`.

Your problem has a lot to do with trying/changing too many things at once without really understanding what is going on. I suggest you go back and read the docs on queries and their methods, and remove `required=True` from your `info` property in the model until such time as you can update all the entities so that `info` has a value.

Comment: To update all entities, is the best method through a push task/queue?